Search two words in the same sentence
I have got a index that it saved articles. The articles index has got abstract and content field. I have set text type for abstract and content mapping.
I wanna search two words what appear in the same sentence in abstract or content field. And also I must check the slop words between theirs.
GET articles/_mapping

Output:
{
  "articles": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "abstract": {
          "type": "text",
        },
        "content {
          "type": "text",
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

I know that I can search in search in each fields by using span_near, but how I can use span_near to search tow words be appeared in the same sentence?

Here is the syntax for using the span_near
GET /articles/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "span_near": {
            "clauses": [
              {
                "span_term": {
                  "abstract": "word1"
                }
              },
              {
                "span_term": {
                  "abstract": "word2"
                }
              }
            ],
            "slop": 0,  
            "in_order": true
          }
        },
        {
          "span_near": {
            "clauses": [
              {
                "span_term": {
                  "content": "word1"
                }
              },
              {
                "span_term": {
                  "content": "word2"
                }
              }
            ],
            "slop": 0,   
            "in_order": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

Note : Adjust the slop values as needed

slop: This defines the maximum number of intervening unmatched positions (words) allowed between the matched terms. A slop of 0 means the words must appear directly next to each other.

in_order - When set to true, it requires the words to appear in the specified order (i.e., word1 must appear before word2). If you don't care about the order, set it to false.


Refer : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-span-near-query.html

Thanks. This syntax is used to search in a field. i have use it. But your query can not search two words by force their appear in the same sentence.
